# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in asp.net mvc controller method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nullreferenceexception

Im having an  " System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."  error whenever i try to insert a new article ......Iv done this same thing without using code first i.e i used the ADO.net data model for already existing DB[Article table,Tag table and ArticleTag table] and it works fine but this time around im trying to use code first EF...i just want someone to look into this for me and maybe help point out my mistake....I can always fall back on DB first where i'll use the  EDMX but i really wanna get my mistake.

```
public class ControlPanelController : Controller
        {
            //
            // GET: /ControlPanel/

           private IPageRepository _repositoryOne;
           private IArticleRepository _repositoryTwo;
            private ITagRepository _repositoryThree;


            public ControlPanelController(IPageRepository repo, IArticleRepository repo2,ITagRepository repo3)
            {
                 _repositoryOne = repo;
                _repositoryTwo = repo2;
                _repositoryThree = repo3;

            }
```

That's my controller.....

Below is the method that's giving the error....

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult ArticleCreator(string title, string mainBody, string addedBy, DateTime dateAdded, string tags)
        {
            Article article = new Article();
            article.Title = title;
            article.ShortBody = ClassAction.TruncateAtWord(mainBody, 500);
            article.MainBody = mainBody;
            article.DateAdded = dateAdded;
            article.AddedBy = addedBy;
            tags = tags ?? string.Empty;
            string[] tagNames = tags.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            foreach (string tagName in tagNames)
            {
                article.Tags.Add(GetTag(tagName));

            }

            _repositoryTwo.SaveArticle(article);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }


 private Tag GetTag(string tagName)
        {
            return _repositoryThree.Tags.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == tagName) ?? new Tag() { Name = tagName };

        }
```

My Entities look like this

```
 public class Article
    {
        [Key]
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public int ArticleId { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string ShortBody { get; set; }
        public string MainBody { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
        public String AddedBy { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; } 


    }


 public class Tag
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You totally  wrong .

```
(string title, string mainBody, string addedBy, DateTime dateAdded, string tags)
```

Above line's is wrong. You dont want to parameter in action result . You can  pass your model class  then you can get values from model class property's ..

Please refer [this :](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3)

**New** **Edit**

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult ArticleCreator(string title, string mainBody, string addedBy, DateTime dateAdded, string tags)
        {
            Article article = new Article();
            article.Title = "TestTitle";
            article.ShortBody = "TestBody";
            article.MainBody = "TestMainBody";
            article.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
            article.AddedBy = "TestName";
            tags = "Test  Tagssss";
            string[] tagNames = tags.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            foreach (string tagName in tagNames)
            {
                article.Tags.Add(GetTag(tagName));

            }

            _repositoryTwo.SaveArticle(article);
            _repositoryTwo.SubmitChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Comment: See my edit . I have assign some values in your property . then add datacontext.submitchanges() . Now check  it

Comment: The problem is actually in the foreach loop with this line giving the error '  article.Tags.Add(GetTag(tagName));'

Comment: Oh . Remove string.Empty 

Just change and try this line 

tags = "Test  Tagssss";